# Is there such a thing as onBlur on ion segment button?

Tags: ionic-framework

I was wondering if there is such a thing as onBlur for ion segment buttons, as I need the functionality of it. I need to change a property to true on a button click and change the property of the button that was deselected to false. How would I be able to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there is no ionBlur on ion segment, instead it has ionChange event which you can use.